# How to avoid non-required template role from being displayed on document?

Tags: docusignapi

I have created one `template` for a document type with different `roles` `i.e. Role1, Role2, Role3`. I am passing the `TemplateId` while creating an `envelope` along with `TemplateRoles(signers)`. But when I am passing the only Role1, Role2 then fields for Role3 also getting displayed on the document.

What I am trying to achieve is like when I will be adding TemplateRole Role1 only then fields for Role2 and Role3 should not be displayed.

Is there anything to configure while creating an `envelope` or need to do something with the template itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending the envelope from the creation call (`status = "sent"`), the empty roles should be discarded automatically.

To get the same behavior in a draft, add the `merge_roles_on_draft=true` query string parameter.

To do so using an SDK, you'll need to leverage a CreateEnvelopesOptions object like so:

```
        EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeOptions createEnvelopeOptions = new EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeOptions()
        {
            mergeRolesOnDraft = "true"
        };
        envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition, createEnvelopeOptions);
```